# URL Parsing not working within Meteor.startup

Tags: javascript, meteor, url-routing

I have a function that takes a string and sets a session based on finding a document in a collection. In this particular case, the string is a possible name for a game `name` and I'll be setting the Session to that game's `_id`

The issue is the function works exactly as expected when I bind it to a template event, but doesn't work at all when I call the function in `Meteor.startup`. FYI - As of right now I'm running autopublish. (I planned to adjust the publish/subscribe settings after this step.)

This is the function that takes the string and sets the session appropriately:

```
var enterExisting = function(n) {
    var g = Games.findOne({name:n});
    var e = "That game doesn't exist.";
    Session.set("error", null);
    Session.set("no_game", null);
    if (Validation.game_exists(n)){
        Validation.clear();
        Session.set("current_game", g._id);
        window.location.hash = ("/" + n);
    } else {
        Session.set("error", e)
    }
};
```

On the home page I use this function on a form, and it works as expected. It sets the session, displays the game, and changes the URL. This is how it's used on that form:

```
Template.entergame.events({
    'click input.enter-game': function(){
    var n = document.getElementById('enter-game-name').value;
    enterExisting(n);
}
});
```

When I try to use the same function in a similar way on `Meteor.startup` it does not set the session or direct me.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set("current_game", "");
    Session.set("error", null);
    Session.set("no_game", null);
    var n = location.hash.substring(2);
    if (n.length === 0) {
        window.location.hash = "#/"
    } else {
        enterExisting(n);
    }
});
```

I don't expect it to be relevant, but just in case here's the template for the "Join a game" form:

```
<template name="entergame">
    <div class="enter-game">
        {{#if error}}
          <p class="error bad-entry">
            {{error}} 
          </p>
        {{/if}}
        <input id="enter-game-name" type="text" placeholder="Join an Existing Game!" />
        <input type="button" class="enter-game" value="»">
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't work, but I recommend: 1) Use http://docs.meteor.com/#session_set_default and 2) Do client-side routing with https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router or the newer https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router rather than roll your own

Answer (score 0):

this should work if you replace the ´Meteor.startup´ with ´Template.entergame.created´

´Meteor.startup´ is for the server and will not execute every time your template is rendered. This is why for every template you have a ´created´ event.

emgee is right: you should use [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) for your client side routing (no server side for now). especially so since iron-router allows you to set the default data for your template on render.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I did get this working and it might be useful to others. I went a tiny step further to improve the clunky UX, but at this time, I plan on removing all of this work in favor of iron router as suggested by Dr Gorb and emgee. This solution breaks down if I simulate a long delay in receiving data from the server.

The issue laid with the publish/subscribe timeline, specifically, that I needed to wait for the subscription to receive data from the server before attempting to render the appropriate template.

The first step was removing autopublish.

Next, I put the URL parsing function into a callback like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set("current_game", "");
    Session.set("error", null);
    Session.set("no_game", null);
    var n = location.hash.substring(2);
    Meteor.subscribe("dice");
    Meteor.subscribe("games", function(){
        if (n.length === 0) {
        window.location.hash = "#/"
        $('.home').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
        enterExisting(n);
        setTimeout(function(){$('.currentgame').fadeIn('slow')}, 1);
    }});
});
```

Here's just the callback that determines which template to load after the subscription returned data:

```
    Meteor.subscribe("games", function(){
        if (n.length === 0) {
        window.location.hash = "#/"
        $('.home').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
        enterExisting(n);
        setTimeout(function(){$('.currentgame').fadeIn('slow')}, 1);
    }});
```

With this solution, the callback function <del>might</del> *probably will* occur after the page has loaded, abruptly switching templates once the data is loaded. So I added a simple solution: Hide the part that might change and fade in the right template when it's ready.

In my CSS:

`.home, .currentgame {display:none;}`

In the JS above, you'll see:

```
    Meteor.subscribe("games", function(){
        .
        .
        .
        $('.home').fadeIn('slow');
        .
        .
        .
        setTimeout(function(){$('.currentgame').fadeIn('slow')}, 1);
    }});
```

As for the `setTimeout`, I really have no explanation, but it got it working. (I suspect it's a matter of queueing that function behind the Session.set stuff.)